# Navigate to Index view of another controller in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am Inside **Index** View of **Home** controller.

I have created one controller called **EstimationTracker** with default **Index** action method. I have also created **Index** view of **EstimationTracker**. But, nothing is there inside **Index** action method of **EstimationTracker** controller.

Now, I want to create **Html.ActionLink** inside **Index** view of **HomeController** to navigate to **Index** view of **EstimationTracker** controller.

I have written the following code to achieve this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Estimation Tracker", "Index", "EstimationTracker", null, new { })
```

In the Browser, if I click on "Estimation Tracker" hyperlink, the page is generating the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8416/EstimationTracker/
```

and popping up the following error:

**HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden**

**The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.**

When I append **Index** to the above URL i.e.:

```
http://localhost:8416/EstimationTracker/Index
```

Now, the page is fine.

How can I make the page run smoothly without any error.

**Update:**

**I'm using Default Routing only.** like below

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: You need to change your routes so that it matches that URL.

Comment: I would ensure that you have a route defined that the above url can resolve to.
Does the Home/Index route have params? You can probably create a shared default route that works for both

Comment: Can you post your code for the controller class and web.config routing, also does the `Index` method on the `EstimationTrackerController` allow the `Get` verb?

Comment: @SLaks: I am using default routing only. I have not modified anything inside RouteConfig.cs

Comment: Do you have a folder in your project named `EstimationTracker`?

Comment: @TGH: As I have modified my post with RouteTable information, I have taken default Route table only. My Home/Index doesn't have any parameters. Do I need to create a shared default route even now? I dont' know but I feel that I don't need to create something shared default route.

Comment: @SLaks: Oh.. what a silly question you are asking man! without EstimationTracker folder, how does the URL:http://localhost:8416/EstimationTracker/Index work?